# I am getting error when I am working on Strapi app using GrapQl

Tags: graphql, strapi

I am following this tutorial https://strapi.io/blog/nextjs-react-hooks-strapi-restaurants-2

My query is

```
{  
  restaurants { 
        id 
        name
    } 
}
```

Response

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Cannot query field \"id\" on type \"RestaurantEntityResponseCollection\".",
        "locations": [
          {
            "line": 3,
            "column": 5
          }
        ],
        "extensions": {
          "code": "GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED",
          "exception": {
            "stacktrace": [
              "GraphQLError: Cannot query field \"id\" on type \"RestaurantEntityResponseCollection\".",
```

Comment: Hi, could you please post your graphql schema?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. It should be clear and descriptive enough to have meaning to a future site user who is skimming through a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem. Your current title is nothing but a repetition of the information already in the tags and the meaningless phrase *I am getting error*, which has no use or value. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You query is incorrect, it should be as follow [docs](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/graphql-api.html#fetch-multiple-entries):

```
 {
  restaurants{
    data{
      id
      attributes{
        name
        image{
          data{
            attributes{
              url
            }
          }
        }
      }
      
    }    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

New strapi versions doesnt work with that old tutorials

```
{
    restaurants {
        data {
            id
            attributes {
                name
                description
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It will resolve data like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "restaurants": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "attributes": {
            "name": "name 1",
            "description": "desc 1"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "attributes": {
            "name": "name 2",
            "description": "desc 2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked for me

**Strapi changes**
Goto - settings-> Roles-> Public-> Permissions section

In this section you need to enable your collection methods, e.g.- find, update, delete and find one

[image]