# Graphql query shows up in console but not in DOM - NuxtJS, Strapi & Graphql

Tags: javascript, html, graphql, nuxt.js, strapi

I have tried to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzlG0L9jlhEPbibzuAQmxJg4FYwRnEyIW, but I am stuck at video 6 and 7 since the data only show up in the console but not in the HTML DOM.

My graphql queries differ from the tutorial as the new Strapi version does not work with the ones in the video ([I am getting error when I am working on Strapi app using GrapQl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70592131/i-am-getting-error-when-i-am-working-on-strapi-app-using-grapql)), but I do not know if that is the issue?

[image]

```
index.vue

<template>
  <div class="home">
   <h1 class="headline center">Lyric Blog</h1>
   <div class="sections">
     <div class="group">
       <div
       v-for="article in articles"
       v-bind:key="article.id"
       class="section">
         <div class="entry">
           <NuxtLink :to="{ path: article.slug, query: {id: article.id} }">
             <h3>
               {{article.title }}
               <span class="subtitle"> {{article.date}} </span>
             </h3>
           </NuxtLink>
 
           <p> {{article.description}} </p>
         </div>
       </div>
 
     </div>
   </div>
 
  </div>
  
 </template>
 
 <script>
 import { allArticles } from '~/graphql/queries'
 
 export default {
  name: 'IndexPage', 
  data() {
     return {
       articles: []
     }
   },
   apollo: {
     articles: {
       prefetch: true,
       query: allArticles
     }
   }
 }
 </script>
```

```
queries.js

import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export const allArticles = gql`
query allArticles {
    articles {
      data {
        id
        attributes {
          title
          slug
          description
          body
          date
        }
      }
    }
}

`
export const singleArticle = gql`
query singleArticle {
    article(id:1) {
      data {
        id
        attributes {
          title
          slug
          description
          body
          date
        }
      }
    }
}

`
```

Comment: Try with `v-for="article in articles.data"` as seen in your devtools.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @kissu. It made a difference in the output in the console, but the DOM is still empty.

https://imgur.com/a/kSHNNoH

Comment: Because then you need `article.attributes.title` as seen in the devtools.